# OnClickListener in AppWidgetProvider

Tags: android, android-intent, android-appwidget, android-pendingintent

I have an AppWidget with a button, the onClick opens an activity, and it works.

```
public class WidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
        final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
        for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
            int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, ActivityPrompt.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.appwidget_button);
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widgetbutton, pendingIntent);  
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
        }
    }
}
```

But now I need to perform more operations when widget is clicked, with this code the onclick action only opens an activity, is it possible to add a onClickListener where I can add more code and operations like in Activities to run before activities opening?

Comment: What kind or operations do you want to perform?

Comment: I need to change a flag in SharedPreference before to open the activity

Comment: that depends what actions you want to perform, Widget can't do all the things with widget that Activity does...

Comment: If it's vital to make it before the Activity starts, consider creating a Service, that will change the flag, start the Activity and the stop itself. Start this Service on the widget's button click.